# Trying to turn json array into a field issue

Tags: json, debugging, jq

I have the following JSON which parses OK:
It is just some term code data that I want to send.

```
[{
"TermCode": 2164,
"ACAD_LEVEL_BOT": "GR",
"ACAD_LEVEL_EOT": "GR",
"ACAD_CAREER": "GRAD",
"UA_PRIM_MAJ_PLN": "DPMDP",
"UA_DEGR_DT": "1900-01-01",
"UA_PRIM_MJ_PLN_DES": "Development Practice",
"UA_PRIM_MIN_PLN_D": "-",
"CUM_GPA": 3.707,
"CUR_GPA": 4,
"TOT_CUMULATIVE": 300,
"UNT_PASSD_PRGRSS": 10,
"UNT_TAKEN_PRGRSS": 10,
"UA_PRIM_MJ_PLN_OWN": "School of Anthropology",
"ADMIT_TYPE": "GRD",
"ADMIT_TERM": "2144",
"UA_FA_ST_RES_DESCR": "Resident",
"VISA_PERMIT_TYPE": "-",
"UA_SALT_ROSTER": "-",
"UA_SALT_STATUS": "-",
"DEGR_CHKOUT_STAT": "-",
"EXP_GRAD_TERM": "-",
"UNT_TRNSFR": 0,
"ACAD_PROG_LD": "Graduate Degree Seeking",
"TOT_TRNSFR": 0,
"TUITION_RES": "RES",
"UA_CITIZEN_COUNTRY": "United States",
"UA_CITIZEN_ST_DESC": "Citizen",
"ACADEMIC_LOAD": "F",
"UNT_AUDIT": 0,
"CAMPUS": "MAIN",
"ACADEMIC_YEAR": "2016-2017",
"UA_DEGREE_LEVEL": "Masters",
"ACAD_PROG": "GDEG",
"UA_SEC_MAJ_PLN": "-",
"ACAD_ORG": "0410",
"EFF_START_DT": "2016-12-18 20:37:08",
"CURRENT_IND": "N",
"PROG_STATUS": "AC",
"PROG_ACTION": "MATR"
```

}]

I want to use this array as a field named term data so I try:

```
[{
termdata: [{
    "TermCode": 2164,
    "ACAD_LEVEL_BOT": "GR",
    "ACAD_LEVEL_EOT": "GR",
    "ACAD_CAREER": "GRAD",
    "UA_PRIM_MAJ_PLN": "DPMDP",
    "UA_DEGR_DT": "1900-01-01",
    "UA_PRIM_MJ_PLN_DES": "Development Practice",
    "UA_PRIM_MIN_PLN_D": "-",
    "CUM_GPA": 3.707,
    "CUR_GPA": 4,
    "TOT_CUMULATIVE": 300,
    "UNT_PASSD_PRGRSS": 10,
    "UNT_TAKEN_PRGRSS": 10,
    "UA_PRIM_MJ_PLN_OWN": "School of Anthropology",
    "ADMIT_TYPE": "GRD",
    "ADMIT_TERM": "2144",
    "UA_FA_ST_RES_DESCR": "Resident",
    "VISA_PERMIT_TYPE": "-",
    "UA_SALT_ROSTER": "-",
    "UA_SALT_STATUS": "-",
    "DEGR_CHKOUT_STAT": "-",
    "EXP_GRAD_TERM": "-",
    "UNT_TRNSFR": 0,
    "ACAD_PROG_LD": "Graduate Degree Seeking",
    "TOT_TRNSFR": 0,
    "TUITION_RES": "RES",
    "UA_CITIZEN_COUNTRY": "United States",
    "UA_CITIZEN_ST_DESC": "Citizen",
    "ACADEMIC_LOAD": "F",
    "UNT_AUDIT": 0,
    "CAMPUS": "MAIN",
    "ACADEMIC_YEAR": "2016-2017",
    "UA_DEGREE_LEVEL": "Masters",
    "ACAD_PROG": "GDEG",
    "UA_SEC_MAJ_PLN": "-",
    "ACAD_ORG": "0410",
    "EFF_START_DT": "2016-12-18 20:37:08",
    "CURRENT_IND": "N",
    "PROG_STATUS": "AC",
    "PROG_ACTION": "MATR"
}]      }]
```

However, this doesn't parse. What is wrong with my syntax?
There is an error in Stack Overflow that is not letting me end my question here so I have to add more description please down down arrow me I didn't have a choice. So my next step would be to have json such as:
[{ termdata:jsonarray,coursedata:jsonarray,admitdata:jsonarray}] 
Any thoughts on that would be appreciated also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To debug small snippets such as yours, you could use https://jsonlint.com,
which gives helpful error messages making it easy to pinpoint the problem.

As an alternative that also works for large files, you might like to consider [`jq`](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/).  With your snippet in the file "input.txt", the invocation:

```
jq empty input.txt
```

produces the error message:

> parse error: Invalid literal at line 2, column 9

This amounts to saying that the first key was not properly quoted.

(Here, `empty` has the effect of suppressing normal output.)

### Let jq do the walking

Better yet, you can save yourself the hassle by letting jq do the work:

```
jq '[{termdata:.}]' original.json
```

This will produce the desired output.  Unless specifically instructed otherwise, jq takes JSON (or a JSON stream) and produces JSON (or a JSON stream).

You could also use jq to do more sophisticated transformations with multiple input files.